# Error with Handlebars, Cannot find module 'node:path'

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, express-handlebars

I am using handlebars to create a small form in node js and it works fine for me on localhost, however when I upload it to a server for testing, it gives me an error when I do the `const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');`

Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM  Require stack:
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.js
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/index.js
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/index.js
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.js:19:14)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM    requireStack: [
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.js',
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/index.js',
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/src/index.js'
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM    ]
Mar 15 07:29:59 PM  }
```

I already have path installed. I'm using render.com

Comment: Can you shre your package.json files with us.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanna let you know, certainly not a long term solution but reverting to express-handlebars@6.0.6 my server started fine.

Answer (score 2):

I also have same situation, seems this is a bug specific to deploy app nodejs express to render.com. the problem is for "express-handlebars" library it seems render.com doesn't support this library since 6.0.0 update. I use `npm install express-handlebars@6.0.6`

```js
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongodb": "^5.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.1.0",
    "mongoose-slug-updater": "^3.3.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "sass": "^1.62.1"
  }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34330119)